# Is Dog related to Wolverine?

Tags: comics, marvel, wolverine

I made a slight fool of myself when the Wolverine: Origin's film came out, touting that they *got it all wrong* saying that:

> Sabretooth (i.e. Dog) is not Wolverine's brother, half or otherwise.

My information is from the cartoon series which treated them separately and as unrelated. I was later informed that this is not true, and that it's alluded to in the comics and hinted at on the [marvel wikia](http://marvel.com/universe/Wolverine_%28James_Howlett%29).

Is this covered anywhere in the comics, or by another authoritative source?

Comment: Any reason for the lack of votes? How can I make this better?

Comment: It's probably quite specific and no-one really has interest. I do though so +1 :)

Comment: Officially, "Dog" Logan and Victor Creed are two totally different people.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There have been conflicts in the comic books about their original relationship.

Let me see:

- In X-Men Forever, Sabretooth is Wolverine's father.
- In the Spiderman newspaper strip Sabretooth is Wolverine's brother.

It is later established that Sabretooth is neither the father or the brother of Wolverine, it is simply a malfunction in his brain from the Weapon X program. His memory has been damaged by more than one organization (apparently Weapon X is just one of them), it is due to this he thinks of Wolverine as a close relative.

Take a look at Wolverine #42 (I think), where it is actually shown that they have no blood connection at all. Also, #50 states that both Wolverine's and Sabretooth's mind have been implanted with false memories.

Comment: Also, just from reading the "Origin" mini-series, it is easy to believe that Dog Logan becomes Sabretooth as he shares many matching characteristics/abilities. The author of the series, however, has publicly stated that they are different people. The movie, however, makes that connection official.

Comment: @phantom42 how official is the subject of a different question though.

Comment: @pureferret That's absolutely fair. After all, Wolverine's creator initially imagined him as an actual cross between a wolverine and a human. But as far as I'm aware and can find, Dog Logan has never been confirmed as Sabretooth in the comics - just implied.

Comment: @phantom42, Len Wein has stated that Wolverine was always a human, never a hybrid. The whole "he was originally half man half wolverine" theory is just an urban myth.

Comment: Frankly, whatever origin he has today until some writer changes their mind and says, "All of the evidence before was fabricated by Weapon X / The Hellfire Club / Professor Xavier for their own nefarious purposes. This is the *real* truth."

Comment: @SeanDuggan Exactly.

Comment: @JordaanMylonas: As above, they will likely waffle on it, but Wein did state that Wolverine was going to be a genetically modified wolverine, but that Stan Lee nixed it. http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2005/10/20/comic-book-urban-legends-revealed-21/